summary statistics using datasummary
I am trying to create a summary statistics tables using datasummary() from modelsummary package, but when I run the code it does not generate any results. This is a minimal example -
datasummary(mpg + hp ~ Mean + Median + P0 + P25 + P50 + P75 + P100 +
            Min + Max + SD + Var,
            data = mtcars)


The results show that - Error in modelsummary::datasummary(mpg + hp ~ Mean + Median + P0 + P25 +  :  object 'Mean' not found
If I use lower case mean and median, the results show that - Error in modelsummary::datasummary(mpg + hp ~ mean + median + P0 + P25 +  :  object 'P0' not found
I use this link - https://rdrr.io/cran/modelsummary/man/P75.html to run the code. Any help is appreciated.

I have been able to solve it. The issue was with the library (modelsummary). Thanks
